# выбрать, кто, когда и какую таблицы создал

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно найти, кто, какую таблицу и когда создал (можно просто, кто является ее владельцем сейчас).
Вот, к чему я пришел:

```sql
select us.principal_id, obj.name, obj.create_date
from sys.objects obj
    join sys.database_principals us on obj.schema_id = us.principal_id
    where obj.type = 'U'
```

Проблема в том, что баз данных, а соответственно, схем, у меня много. Нужно объединить в одном запросе данные из несколько баз данных.
Думаю, можно заменить `sys.database_principals` на `sys.server_principals`. Тогда можно будет для каждого логина выбирать его таблицы. Но опять же получается что в пределах одной базы. Так вот, как сделать выборку для всех баз, в пределах одного сервера?

Comment: Это вообще никак нельзя сделать без специального логирования, потому что создатель таблицы не сохраняется нигде

Comment: @DenisRubashkin ну, да, я понял. Хорошо, тогда если не создателя, а владельца?

Comment: Владелец - sys.objects.principal_id, но только если отличается от владельца схемы, если NULL, то нужно брать sys.schemas.principal_id. Если нужно из нескольких баз, то нужно тогда по всем базам пробежаться

Comment: @DenisRubashkin вот у меня в том-то и проблема, как пробежаться по всем базам. Нельзя же для каждого запроса писать `use db_name`. Ну или можно, но это как-то глупо. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @ExitBotadeus EXEC sp_MSforeachdb command